# Debugger does not stop at breakpoints in Eclipse when debugging on an existing android project

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I have imported an existing android project into eclipse, using the import existing android project option in eclipse. While debugging, the debugger won't stop at the breakpoints. I have taken the below mentioned steps till now:

1. Tried executing the application in Debug perspective.
2. Enable debug mode in the Android Manifest file.
3. Tried placing the breakpoints at various points in the program.
4. Uninstalled Eclipse and re-installed again

But none of the above mentioned steps helped.

However, if I try creating a new test android application project and apply breakpoints there, it seems to be working fine. The problem is with the existing android application that has been imported.

PS: The existing android application source code is in a folder other than the default eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your code. At the onCreate

```
 android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```